# How can I use PHP to validate a drop down list

Tags: php

I want to validate a form using PHP. Below is the sample of my form:

```
<form>
    <select name="select_box">
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">OPT 1</option>
        <option value="2">OPT 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Comment: what thing you are exactly trying to validate?i think you need to explain more about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['select_box']) && $_REQUEST['select_box'] == '0') { 
  echo 'Please select a country.'; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your php script where are you are submitting your form (in this case it's the same script that echoes out the form, since you aren't specifying `action` and `method` attribute to your `<form>`), you can get values of inputs by doing `$_GET['name_of_input']`, which in your case:

`if(isset($_GET['select_box'])) { // do something with value of drop down`

Comment: Hi Nifty, here is what my code looks like.http://codepad.org/hld1m38z this just an example cos am my real code is validating a country field. please check this out and let me know the exact place to include the function you just gave me, and i also need an error message in case if the user click a submit button without selecting the country field.

Comment: @ApuloOhaleCosmasLite Above your `<select>`, `<?php if(isset($_GET['select_box']) && $_GET['select_box'] == '0') { echo 'Please select a country.'; } ?>`

Comment: @ApuloOhaleCosmasLite You can thank me by clicking on the greyed out V sign below the number  0 on the top left of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_GET['select_box'] != '0') //form validation
{
 //your code here
}
?>
```